# How to abstract a date time stamp in three separate column in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet in which the column A2:A3000 contains several date and time stamp exactly as this format : **20-AUG-2013 23:07:00 - 23:17:00**

Is it possible to have a formula (preferably a single formula) that could extra these data in such a way that -

1) the date goes in Column B as : **20-AUG-2013**

2) the start time goes in C as  : **23:07:00**

3) & the end time goes in D as  : **23:17:00**

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: http://anandexcels.wordpress.com/tag/mid-function-in-google-docs/

Comment: How does 2nd August display? 02 or 2?

Comment: 2nd August is displayed as 02. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In B1 enter:
=MID(A1,1,11)  and copy down

In C1 enter:
=MID(A1,13,8)  and copy down

In D1 enter:
=RIGHT(A1,8)  and copy down

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=if(column()=2;mid($A1;1;11);if(column()=3;mid($A1;13;9);mid($A1;23;9)))
```

*Edit re comment to OP*

I got lucky with just guessing that `2` Aug 2013 would present as `02` but in case not, would be better to cover both possibilities with:

```
=if(column()=2;mid($A1;1;11);if(column()=3;mid($A1;12;9);mid($A1;23;9)))
```

ie picking up an extra space is less 'dangerous' than missing off a digit.